# "Enable context menus and dragging and dropping" is missing from Start Menu Properties

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, 64-bit, context-menu

Right context menus are missing when I try to right click on an icon in my start menu, for example if I want to run as administrator.

I've found a couple places on the web that suggest that I need to go to Taskbar and Start Menu Properties -> Customize and then tick the "Enable context menus and dragging and dropping" option there.  Well, it's not there in my Customize Start Menu.  In the list of Start Menu Properties see Downloads followed by Favorites menu.

Any idea how I can reenable the context menu in the Start Menu?  I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Open Regedit.exe and go to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Delete the registry value named "NoChangeStartMenu".

Check for the value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as well.

Policy:Disable drag-and-drop menus on the Start Menu
Description:Prevents users from modifying the Start menu by dragging and 
dropping items. Other methods of customizing the Start menu are still 
enabled.